# How to use SharedPreferences for splash activity to launch once

Tags: java, android

I want to launch splash activity only once using SharedPreference, how it could be happen. any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
Thread thread;
MediaPlayer audio;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    audio = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.iphone);
    audio.start();


    if (first_run == true){
    thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(4000);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                finish();
                audio.release();
            }
        }
    };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Declare

```
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String ID = "idKey";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

Now in your onCreate():

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    audio = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.iphone);
    audio.start();
    String first = (sharedPreferences.getString("First", ""));
    if (!first.equals("true")) {
        thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(4000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashTwo.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("First", "true");
                    editor.commit();
                    finish();
                    audio.release();
                }
            }
        };
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mohammad Farhan if the answer works...mark it as correct..thnkx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sharedprefrence` ,i would like to suggest you to use static boolean value like - `isFirstTime` and set it `true` by default and on second activity (next to splash) set it to `false`. Whenever you kill app static value will become dead.Check in `onCreate` of Splash -

```
if(!isFirstTime){
    goToNextActivity();
 }else{
//continue splash code
}
```

If you want to use shared preference then use same Logic ,take a boolean value and save it in shared pref -

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,     MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", true);
 editor.commit();
```

and in next activity simply set it to `false` or clear value. by calling `editor.clear();` and put a check in splash if shared pref has some value or have `isFirstTime` and do next code accordingly.